# Automation form filling

Tags: java, html, forms, matlab, automation

I am helping 60 of my students to get their first jobs. Last year I did the same things by hand, it took me 2 months for helping 72 students.  I want to write a program to help them submit resumes and apply jobs in some companies.

I hope the program can do two things

1. creates account for each students in careerbuilder.com/monster.com etc and upload their resumes.
2. submit their information to companies that look for people

What program should I use to do that? Some clear guidelines to do that?
If I pay for someone to make this program, how much will it cost?

I am good in Matlab, but am willing to learn any language to do this program

Comment: Irrelevant question: shouldn't your students be doing this stuff themselves?  This is a skill they should learn.

Comment: @Jay: Writing automated form fillers is an important life skill?

Comment: @jrtayloriv I was thinking more about the stuff the OP wants to do for his students.

Comment: Ahhh, now it makes sense. I was wondering what you were thinking :) ... sorry about that! You're absolutely right as far as them needing to learn how to do that themselves.

Comment: They are kids and need people to push them, help them to get their first jobs. I do as much as I can for them and hope they will have good lives.

Comment: I suspect sites like these try to prevent automation since it could easily be abused by spammers. Why not make getting an account on these sites and uploading a resume part of class requirements?

Comment: @Marco: there should be more teachers like you :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think Matlab would be a good option for this sort of thing. Probably Perl/PHP as it will require some online form filling. They both provide you access to CURL library which is good for online form processing.

Answer (score 0):

I would take a look at the Perl module [WWW::Mechanize::FormFiller](http://search.cpan.org/~corion/WWW-Mechanize-FormFiller-0.10/lib/WWW/Mechanize/FormFiller.pm)